# Como mudar cor de background de acordo com o valor

Tags: javascript, css

Montei um script para contar caracteres de um `textarea` em JavaScript, o código é esse:

```html
<div>
    <p class="texto-cont">Restam <span id="cont">2.200</span> caracteres</p>
</div>
```

```js
function limite_textarea(valor) {
    quant = 2200;
    total = valor.length;
    if(total <= quant) {
        resto = quant - total;
        document.getElementById("cont").innerHTML = resto;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("texto").value = valor.substr(0,quant);
    }
}
```

Preciso mudar o `background` do trecho *"Restam 2.200 caracteres"*. Quando estiver em 2.200 gostaria que o `background` ficasse verde, laranja em 2000 e vermelho em 100 caracteres.

Comment: Já tentou `document.getElementById("cont").style.backgroundColor = "red"` ?

Comment: Como poderia aplicar nesse caso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta utilizar um `if` ou operação ternária e utilizar a propriedade `element.style.backgroundColor`.

**Exemplo:**

```js
/**
 * Captura os elementos
 */
const content = document.querySelector("#content")
const count = document.querySelector("#count")

/**
 * Utiliza o evento "input" para detectar novas alterações no textarea
 */
content.addEventListener("input", () => {

  /**
   * Captura o valor do atributo "maxlength" e 
   * calcula a quantidade restantes de caracteres
   */
  let maxLength = parseInt(content.getAttribute('maxlength'))
  let charRemaining = maxLength - content.value.length
  
  /* Converte o valor para pt-BR (Adiciona o "." em caso de milhar) */
  count.textContent = charRemaining.toLocaleString()
  
  /**
   * Utiliza uma operação ternária para verificar a quantidade de caracteres restantes
   * Se a qnt. restante for maior que 2190 => Verde, caso contrário realiza outra opção ternária
   * Se a qnt. restante for maior que 2180 e menor que 2190 => Laranja, caso contrário utiliza o vermelho
   */
  count.style.color = charRemaining > 2190 ? 'green' : charRemaining > 2180 ? 'orange' : 'red'
  content.style.backgroundColor = charRemaining > 2190 ? '#00800026' : charRemaining > 2180 ? '#ffa50026' : '#ff000026'
})

content.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"))
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea id="content" rows="10" maxlength="2200"></textarea>
 <p class="texto-cont">Restam <span id="count"></span> caracteres</p>
</div>
```

---

Caso você utilize algum *plugin* para *WYSIWYG* ou similar, é necessário que esse permita que você "ouça" alguns eventos como `keydown`, `keyup`, `input` etc. Nem sempre isso irá acontecer. No exemplo abaixo, utilizarei o projeto [**emojionearea**](https://github.com/mervick/emojionearea), porém poderá não funcionar com outros.

**Exemplo comentando:**

```js
const maxLength = 2200
const emojionearea = $("#emojionearea1").emojioneArea({
  events: {
    /**
     * Informa a função callback do evento `keyup`
     * Caso queira utilizar outro evento, basta dá
     * uma olhada na documentação:
     * https://github.com/mervick/emojionearea#events
     */
    keyup: (editor) => { charRemaining(editor[0]) }
  }
})


function charRemaining(editor) {
  /**
   * Captura o valor do atributo "maxlength" e 
   * calcula a quantidade restantes de caracteres
   */
  let charRemaining = maxLength - editor.textContent.length

  /* Converte o valor para pt-BR (Adiciona o "." em caso de milhar) */
  count.textContent = charRemaining.toLocaleString()

  /**
   * Utiliza uma operação ternária para verificar a quantidade de caracteres restantes
   * Se a qnt. restante for maior que 2190 => Verde, caso contrário realiza outra opção ternária
   * Se a qnt. restante for maior que 2180 e menor que 2190 => Laranja, caso contrário utiliza o vermelho
   */
  count.style.color = charRemaining > 2190 ? 'green' : charRemaining > 2180 ? 'orange' : 'red'
  count.style.backgroundColor = charRemaining > 2190 ? '#00800026' : charRemaining > 2180 ? '#ffa50026' : '#ff000026'
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojionearea/3.4.1/emojionearea.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojionearea/3.4.1/emojionearea.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6">
    <textarea id="emojionearea1"></textarea>
  </div>
  
  <p class="texto-cont">Restam <span id="count">2.200</span> caracteres</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Funcionou em localhost, mas quando implementei o código em meu site, não funcionou, o servidor deu erro na declaração const. Eu alterei para var. ai o código conseguiu mostrar os caracteres, mas parou de contar e de mudar o background.

Comment: O meu código está com o código input, mas o campo text area está representado por uma div, ai a contagem não é feita, pois a entrada de dados está sendo feita no div.

O código div só aparece quando abro a página, no código do php ele não aparece, por isso não consigo definir a classe do div e declarar no javascript. Como faço para resolver?

Comment: @Rodrigo , você está usando uma `div` com a propriedade `contenteditable`, é isso? Se for isso, basta fazer dessa maneira: https://codepen.io/valdeir2000/pen/LgMXeX?editors=1010

Comment: O erro com `const` pode ter sido gerado devido a versão do navegador, para uma maior compatibilidade você pode usar o `BabelJs`

Comment: Valdeir, a div é contenteditable sim, porém, ela já tem uma class div definida, e não consigo encontrar o arquivo onde está esse código. No codepen o código que você informou funcionou, mas como eu não consigo encontrar o código para declarar o maxlength na div, eu declarei no código, ficando assim: https://codepen.io/rodson-rodrigo/pen/dgabNR Você vai ver que funciona, mas quando insiro no meu site, ele não funciona, e no depurador aparece o erro Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined at

Comment: @Rodrigo , o erro acontece pois a `div` não foi encontrada (caso a `div` esteja em um `iframe`, você não vai conseguir acessá-la). Nesse caso você pode definir uma constante com o valor máximo: https://codepen.io/valdeir2000/pen/yRZBoB

Comment: Agora o erro sumiu, porém ainda continua sem fazer a contagem, e apresentando o erro Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null al

Comment: Só pra ajudar, eu desejo fazer isso no emojionearea.

Comment: @Rodrigo Informação importante. Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Boa tarde, eu acabei não executando  essa atualização, por ventura fiz hoje e funcionou. Gostaria agora de apenas de mudar todo o background da classe .texto-cont do texto "Restam xxx caracteres" conforme a quantidade de caracteres vai diminuindo.